# Create correct certificates and provisioning profiles in a development team

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning-profile

I struggle since a few days to get a correct provisioning profile.

I am an independent iOS dev with my own iTunes connect account but I recently started to develop for a development team. Since then, I can't get a correct provisionning profile to run my app from xCode to my iPhone.

iOS documentation describes how to create certificates and provisionning profiles but it doesn't identify who needs to do each step (either me the developer, either the development team manager).

Could you please describe who needs to do the following step :
1. Create a development certificate. To me, it should be me as it is me who develops. Then, I send it to the dev team manager who adds it in his member center.
2. App ID : The dev team manager create the app ID with a specific bundle ID
3. Devices : The dev team manager adds my iPhone UDID.
4. Provisioning profile : The dev team manager creates it from my certificates, the app ID and my device. Then, he sends me the file and I just have to double-click on it.

However, this doesn't seem to work. Any idea how I can obtain a valid provisioning profile.

PS 1 : I have been added in Itunes Connect and I can access to the app details.
PS 2 : Bundle ID of the app in xCode and iTunes connect are the same (I've checked a hundred times).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each team member is responsible for creating their own key/cert pair and adding it to their machine via Keychain Access.  That is for Development builds.  Distribution certs can only be created by an admin.

To create an app Id or provision on the member center you need to have admin access.  If you don't have admin access then you have to rely on someone who does to create those.  They would be responsible for making sure your device and cert are attached to then development provision for your app.

Your problem could also be that your code signing settings are not setup correctly in the project.  You should set provision to Automatic and identity to iOSDeveloper.  This lets Xcode figure it out and also allows you to share the project in a team setting without code signing issues

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here are the steps:

1. Generate a new CSR from Keychain.
2. Go to iTunes Connect.
3. In Certificate section:

   - Download Apple's World Wide Relations Authority Certificate using CSR.
   - Download iOS Developer Certificate using CSR.
4. Add both these certificates to Keychain.
5. In Provisional Profile Section:

   - Download a new provisional profile which includes this developer certificate.
6. Add this profile to Xcode.
7. In Xcode, go to Build Settings --> Code Signing --> Set provisional profile.
8. Run project.

This should do it for you.
Good luck.